# Error due to "BuildRequires: maven-local" in spec file for Packaging Maven project

Tags: maven, rpm, rpm-spec

**Issue** : I am following the URL. https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/java-packaging-howto/packaging_maven_project/ to create a spec file for the rpm package.

In the website  "BuildRequires:  maven-local" is mentioned in the spec file.

but when I tried to search 'maven-local' using  `yum search maven-local` command, I could not find anything and as I was not able to install the component, I'm getting an error when I am trying to do rpmbuild.

**Note:** I even installed maven separately in my system but it did not help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Some RPMs are here - https://pkgs.org/download/maven-local . Any non-RPM installed version of _any software_ will not satisfy RPM requirements.

Comment: Thank you.
I was able to fix the issue by installing  'maven.noarch'

```yum install maven.noarch```
and added "buildRequired : maven" in the spec file.